# Instagram oauth login data not available when page is refresh

Tags: php, api, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I am implementing `instagram` OAuth login script with php first time and facing some issues with API. When I am login with my instagram account it will be redirecting to me on my redirect url which I have set on instagram client. After redirecting to my redirected page, I am getting all my information about my user which is okay but when I refresh page all instagram user details are gone. :(

Any idea how to fix that issue? I also trying by myself to fix this issue but need support if possible.

### file structure with code:

config.php

```
<?php
    define('YOUR_APP_KEY', '');
    define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', '');
    define('YOUR_APP_CALLBACK', 'http://localhost/instagram-login/');
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'instagram.class.php';
    require 'config.php';
    $instagram = new Instagram(array(
        'apiKey'      => YOUR_APP_KEY,
        'apiSecret'   => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
        'apiCallback' => YOUR_APP_CALLBACK
    ));

    $code = $_GET['code'];
    if(true === isset($code)){
        //$data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);

        // Receive OAuth token object
        $data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $data;

        // Store user access token
        $instagram->setAccessToken($data);

        // Get user follows
        $following = $instagram->getUserFollows();

        // Display all user follower
        foreach ($following->data as $user) {
          echo 'ID: ' . $user->id . ' Name: ' . $user->username . '<br/>';
        }
    }else{
        $loginUrl   = $instagram->getLoginUrl();
        echo "<a class=\"button\" href=\"$loginUrl\">Sign in with Instagram</a>";
    }
?>
```

instagram.class.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Instagram API class
 * API Documentation: http://instagram.com/developer/
 * Class Documentation: https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API/blob/master/README.markdown
 * 
 * @author Christian Metz
 * @since 30.10.2011
 * @copyright Christian Metz - MetzWeb Networks 2012
 * @version 1.9
 * @license BSD http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php
 */

class Instagram
{

    /**
     * The API base URL
     */
    const API_URL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/';

    /**
     * The API OAuth URL
     */
    const API_OAUTH_URL = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize';

    /**
     * The OAuth token URL
     */
    const API_OAUTH_TOKEN_URL = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';

    /**
     * The Instagram API Key
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $_apikey;

    /**
     * The Instagram OAuth API secret
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $_apisecret;

    /**
     * The callback URL
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $_callbackurl;

    /**
     * The user access token
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $_accesstoken;

    /**
     * Available scopes
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    private $_scopes = array('basic', 'likes', 'comments', 'relationships');

    /**
     * Available actions
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    private $_actions = array('follow', 'unfollow', 'block', 'unblock', 'approve', 'deny');


    /**
     * Default constructor
     *
     * @param array|string $config          Instagram configuration data
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($config)
    {
        if (true === is_array($config)) {
            // if you want to access user data
            $this->setApiKey($config['apiKey']);
            $this->setApiSecret($config['apiSecret']);
            $this->setApiCallback($config['apiCallback']);
        } else if (true === is_string($config)) {
            // if you only want to access public data
            $this->setApiKey($config);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Error: __construct() - Configuration data is missing.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates the OAuth login URL
     *
     * @param array [optional] $scope       Requesting additional permissions
     * @return string                       Instagram OAuth login URL
     */
    public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('basic'))
    {
        if (is_array($scope) && count(array_intersect($scope, $this->_scopes)) === count($scope)) {
            return self::API_OAUTH_URL . '?client_id=' . $this->getApiKey() . '&redirect_uri=' . $this->getApiCallback() . '&scope=' . implode('+', $scope) . '&response_type=code';
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Error: getLoginUrl() - The parameter isn't an array or invalid scope permissions used.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Search for a user
     *
     * @param string $name                  Instagram username
     * @param integer [optional] $limit     Limit of returned results
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function searchUser($name, $limit = 0)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('users/search', false, array(
            'q' => $name,
            'count' => $limit
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get user info
     *
     * @param integer [optional] $id        Instagram user id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUser($id = 0)
    {
        $auth = false;
        if ($id === 0 && isset($this->_accesstoken)) {
            $id   = 'self';
            $auth = true;
        }
        return $this->_makeCall('users/' . $id, $auth);
    }

    /**
     * Get user activity feed
     *
     * @param integer [optional] $limit     Limit of returned results
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserFeed($limit = 0)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('users/self/feed', true, array(
            'count' => $limit
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get user recent media
     *
     * @param integer [optional] $id        Instagram user id
     * @param integer [optional] $limit     Limit of returned results
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserMedia($id = 'self', $limit = 0)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('users/' . $id . '/media/recent', true, array(
            'count' => $limit
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get the liked photos of a user
     *
     * @param integer [optional] $limit     Limit of returned results
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserLikes($limit = 0)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('users/self/media/liked', true, array(
            'count' => $limit
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get the list of users this user follows
     *
     * @param integer [optional] $id        Instagram user id
     * @param integer [optional] $limit     Limit of returned results
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserFollows($id = 'self', $limit = 0)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('users/' . $id . '/follows', true, array(
            'count' => $limit
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get the list of users this user is followed by
     *
     * @param integer [optional] $id        Instagram user id
     * @param integer [optional] $limit     Limit of returned results
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserFollower($id = 'self', $limit = 0)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('users/' . $id . '/followed-by', true, array(
            'count' => $limit
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get information about a relationship to another user
     *
     * @param integer $id                   Instagram user id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserRelationship($id)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('users/' . $id . '/relationship', true);
    }

    /**
     * Modify the relationship between the current user and the target user
     *
     * @param string $action                Action command (follow/unfollow/block/unblock/approve/deny)
     * @param integer $user                 Target user id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function modifyRelationship($action, $user)
    {
        if (true === in_array($action, $this->_actions) && isset($user)) {
            return $this->_makeCall('users/' . $user . '/relationship', true, array(
                'action' => $action
            ), 'POST');
        }
        throw new Exception("Error: modifyRelationship() | This method requires an action command and the target user id.");
    }

    /**
     * Search media by its location
     *
     * @param float $lat                    Latitude of the center search coordinate
     * @param float $lng                    Longitude of the center search coordinate
     * @param integer [optional] $distance  Distance in meter (max. distance: 5km = 5000)
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function searchMedia($lat, $lng, $distance = 1000)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('media/search', false, array(
            'lat' => $lat,
            'lng' => $lng,
            'distance' => $distance
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get media by its id
     *
     * @param integer $id                   Instagram media id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMedia($id)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('media/' . $id);
    }

    /**
     * Get the most popular media
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPopularMedia()
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('media/popular');
    }

    /**
     * Search for tags by name
     *
     * @param string $name                  Valid tag name
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function searchTags($name)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('tags/search', false, array(
            'q' => $name
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get info about a tag
     *
     * @param string $name                  Valid tag name
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTag($name)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('tags/' . $name);
    }

    /**
     * Get a recently tagged media
     *
     * @param string $name                  Valid tag name
     * @param integer [optional] $limit     Limit of returned results
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTagMedia($name, $limit = 0)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('tags/' . $name . '/media/recent', false, array(
            'count' => $limit
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get a list of users who have liked this media
     *
     * @param integer $id                   Instagram media id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMediaLikes($id)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('media/' . $id . '/likes', true);
    }

    /**
     * Set user like on a media
     *
     * @param integer $id                   Instagram media id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function likeMedia($id)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('media/' . $id . '/likes', true, null, 'POST');
    }

    /**
     * Remove user like on a media
     *
     * @param integer $id                   Instagram media id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function deleteLikedMedia($id)
    {
        return $this->_makeCall('media/' . $id . '/likes', true, null, 'DELETE');
    }

    /**
     * Get the OAuth data of a user by the returned callback code
     *
     * @param string $code                  OAuth2 code variable (after a successful login)
     * @param boolean [optional] $token     If it's true, only the access token will be returned
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getOAuthToken($code, $token = false)
    {
        $apiData = array(
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => $this->getApiKey(),
            'client_secret' => $this->getApiSecret(),
            'redirect_uri' => $this->getApiCallback(),
            'code' => $code
        );

        $result = $this->_makeOAuthCall($apiData);
        return (false === $token) ? $result : $result->access_token;
    }

    /**
     * The call operator
     *
     * @param string $function              API resource path
     * @param array [optional] $params      Additional request parameters
     * @param boolean [optional] $auth      Whether the function requires an access token
     * @param string [optional] $method     Request type GET|POST
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function _makeCall($function, $auth = false, $params = null, $method = 'GET')
    {
        if (false === $auth) {
            // if the call doesn't requires authentication
            $authMethod = '?client_id=' . $this->getApiKey();
        } else {
            // if the call needs an authenticated user
            if (true === isset($this->_accesstoken)) {
                $authMethod = '?access_token=' . $this->getAccessToken();
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Error: _makeCall() | $function - This method requires an authenticated users access token.");
            }
        }

        if (isset($params) && is_array($params)) {
            $paramString = '&' . http_build_query($params);
        } else {
            $paramString = null;
        }

        $apiCall = self::API_URL . $function . $authMethod . (('GET' === $method) ? $paramString : null);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiCall);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Accept: application/json'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        if ('POST' === $method) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ltrim($paramString, '&'));
        } else if ('DELETE' === $method) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
        }

        $jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($jsonData);
    }

    /**
     * The OAuth call operator
     *
     * @param array $apiData                The post API data
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function _makeOAuthCall($apiData)
    {
        $apiHost = self::API_OAUTH_TOKEN_URL;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiHost);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($apiData));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($apiData));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Accept: application/json'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $jsonData = curl_exec($ch);

        if (false === $jsonData) {
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($jsonData);
    }

    /**
     * Access Token Setter
     * 
     * @param object|string $data
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAccessToken($data)
    {
        (true === is_object($data)) ? $token = $data->access_token : $token = $data;
        $this->_accesstoken = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Access Token Getter
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAccessToken()
    {
        return $this->_accesstoken;
    }

    /**
     * API-key Setter
     * 
     * @param string $apiKey
     * @return void
     */
    public function setApiKey($apiKey)
    {
        $this->_apikey = $apiKey;
    }

    /**
     * API Key Getter
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getApiKey()
    {
        return $this->_apikey;
    }

    /**
     * API Secret Setter
     * 
     * @param string $apiSecret 
     * @return void
     */
    public function setApiSecret($apiSecret)
    {
        $this->_apisecret = $apiSecret;
    }

    /**
     * API Secret Getter
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getApiSecret()
    {
        return $this->_apisecret;
    }

    /**
     * API Callback URL Setter
     * 
     * @param string $apiCallback
     * @return void
     */
    public function setApiCallback($apiCallback)
    {
        $this->_callbackurl = $apiCallback;
    }

    /**
     * API Callback URL Getter
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getApiCallback()
    {
        return $this->_callbackurl;
    }

}
```